# Remove personal information from a chat discussion that is already frozen

Tags: support, status-completed

Due to privacy concerns I want to remove personal information from a message in a chat discussion that is already frozen, and I am therefore unable to edit it. How can I do that?

Comment: Your only option is to get a link to the message you want delete and then custom flag one of your own posts on SO main and ask the mod to delete the chat message [link]. Add that you can't do it yourself and that the chat message contains PII.

Comment: Thanks. Just did that and am waiting for the outcome!

Comment: So how are you quantifying personal information?  Something that can be used to identify you as a person or some sort of system credentials?  The only chat room that can be found of you with anything like that (by the way, Chat is publicly searchable) is a room with you talking over some details of what looks to be a programming question.  At first blush I'm not seeing anything "personal" in there at all...

Comment: My definition of PII (Personally identifiable information) can be found [here](https://www.dol.gov/general/ppii) and elsewhere. But thanks to @rene, the moderator has removed the PII, and it is fine now.